# Can we strengthen the axiom of choice to settle the generalized continuum problem?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

By the generalized continuum problem, I mean the following: given an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, find the order type of the set of all cardinals strictly between $\kappa$ and $2^\kappa$.

Now whenever $Y$ and $X$ denote sets and $R : X \nrightarrow Y$ is a relation, define that $R$ satisfies the *dispersion condition* iff firstly, for all $x \in X$ we have that $R_*(x) \neq \emptyset_Y$, and secondly, it holds that for all distinct $x',x \in X$, we have $R_*(x') \cap R_*(x) = \emptyset_Y$. In this language, the axiom of choice can be stated:

> **AC.** Every relation satisfying the dispersion condition has a subinjection.

What I'd like to know is:

> **Question.** Can we weaken the dispersion condition in the above formulation of the axiom of choice (call the stronger axiom obtained in this way AC+) in such a way that AC+ settles the generalized continuum problem, and hopefully other questions independent of the usual axioms of set theory, without contradicting the existence of large cardinals or anything nasty like that?

Lets discuss this a bit.

In graph theory, we have the following result. As before, let $Y$ and $X$ denote sets, and $R : X \nrightarrow Y$ denote a binary relation. Define that $R$ satisfies the *Hall condition* iff for all subsets $A$ of $X$, we have $|R(A)| \geq |A|$. In this language, Hall's marriage theorem says:

> **Theorem.** Every relation **between finite sets** satisfying the Hall condition has a subinjection.

Unfortunately, the analogous theorem for infinite sets fails. The standard counterexample is as follows. Define a relation $R : \mathbb{N} \nrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as follows.

- $R_*(0) = \mathbb{N}$
- for all non-zero $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $R_*(n) = \{n-1\}$.

Then $R$ satisfies the Hall condition, but has no subinjection.

So, we're looking for a requirement intermediate between the Hall condition (which is too weak) and the dispersion condition (which is too strong).

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: By 'subinjection', I assume you mean a subrelation that is an injective function? I've not seen the term used before.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, yep; its a made-up term, but seems self-explanatory enough that I thought it was safe not to define it. I also like the term "subfunction." One version of the axiom of choice says: "every total relation has a subfunction."

Comment: I don't think 'subfunction' is standard either, but let it pass. What leads you to suspect that any of this would have a bearing on GCH?  (Also, I think your dispersion condition needs to be fixed: is $f$ supposed to be the characteristic function $f: X \to P(Y)$ of the relation $R$?)

Comment: @ToddTrimble GCH implies AC, so it is not entirely unreasonable that a suitable strengthening of AC would be able to decide the continuum function (For instance, GCH is such a strengthening.) Presumably the question is about strengthenings that at least in spirit look choice-like.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo I am indeed aware of GCH implies AC. But my question still stands.

Comment: This formulation of AC is a terrible terrible *terrible* way of saying "Every relation $R$ has a function $f\subseteq R$ with the same domain".

Comment: @AsafKaragila, for the purposes of this question, the problem with that version of AC is that it has no potential to be strengthened by weakening the conditions on $R$, because there *are* no conditions on $R$, because all we're asking for is a subfunction. That's why I'm using the subinjection formulation here.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, to answer your second question; I have no particular reason to think that a strengthening of AC could settle the generalized continuum problem, except for the fact that GCH implies AC, and the feeling emanating from Hall's marriage theorem that there might be more powerful choice principles, and the feeling that combinatorial axioms (like a strengthened axiom of choice) should be "more powerful" than axioms like GCH which merely assert something about the structure of a decategorified $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: The question as stated has the following (unsatisfactory) answer:  weaken the dispersion condition to allow every binary relation. Now, the version of AC+ that you get from that, where the conclusion gives you an sub-injection, is refutable, since perhaps $R$ is already a function, but not injective. So this weakening makes AC+ contradictory, and hence implies GCH and settles many other questions, in all possible ways. But I suppose this answer is not what you intend.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, well, its not supposed to refute the existence of large cardinals, so consistency would certainly be a good first step in that direction :)

Comment: By a result of Mansfield the existence of a  locally $Σ_1$-definable well-order of $H(ω_1)$ implies $CH$.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, to give a little more: it might be possible to prove GCH using a strengthened axiom of choice AC+ as follows: first, assign to each cardinal $\kappa$ a special relation $R_\kappa : 2^\kappa \nrightarrow \kappa^+$. Then prove that $R_\kappa$ is "sufficiently dispersive" that some kind of AC+ axiom implies that it has a subinjection. Hence conclude that $2^\kappa = \kappa^+$. Personally, however, I'm more interested in strengthenings of AC that imply the existence of at least one cardinal $\kappa$ satisfying $2^\kappa \neq \kappa^+.$